# How to handle error and get current recording video size using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, swift3

I am using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput for recording videos since I need video and audio frame. How we can handle error while recording, such as 'no disk space'/'recording stopped'. While recording using AVCaptureMovieFileOutput we can get the error in :

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!)
```

And also how we can track or get the video file size of current recording video.
Using AVCaptureMovieFileOutput we can get the size of video while recording by keeping the reference of  'AVCaptureFileOutput' in 'startRecording' delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to conform to the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` of your `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and utilize a method called [`captureOutput(_:didOutput:from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate/1385775-captureoutput). This method will notify your delegate when a new video frame has been written to and which connection it was written from. From inside this method I would read the [buffer size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31442475/3911918) of your output and then compare this with your available space on disk:

```
if let systemAttributes = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfFileSystem(forPath: NSHomeDirectory() as String) {
    if let availableSpace = systemAttributes[FileAttributeKey.systemFreeSize] as? NSNumber {
        print("Available Space \(availableSpace.int64Value)")
    }
}
```

This way you will get notified of whenever the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` outputs a video frame, and if the size of the recording is approaching a threshold close to your available space on disk then you can stop the recording and alert your user they have run out of space for their video.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried but while getting the buffer size am getting Buffer Size: 1080:1920 for every buffer samples. How we can check the size of the recording is approaching a threshold close to your available space on disk.

Comment: I need to stop the recording when the free space < 0.5MB. and should save that much recorded video